# Using `\r` character in system call to write(2)

Tags: c

I'm trying to print numbers in the terminal. The numbers must be printed in the same location. So `1` should be printed then `1` will be removed and `2` will be printed and so on. I'm using the following C-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    useconds_t milisecs;
    milisecs = 500000;
    int i;
    char buffer[1024];

    /* print numbers in-place */
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        printf("%d\r",i);
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(milisecs);
    }

    /* print numbers in-place using write() */
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d\r", i);
        write(1,buffer,1);
        usleep(milisecs);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The first for-loop uses `printf()` and works as I expect. However the second loop with `write()` prints `0123456789`.  How can I get the second loop to output the same text as the first loop? I think the problem has to do with `\r` not being recognized by `write()`.

Comment: Can you use `ncurses`?

Comment: No I don't have that library at this moment.

Comment: you could try using `\b` the back space, or you could try using ANSI escape sequences to properly handle the cursor positioning on the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffer contains the digit and the CR (two characters), but you are writing only a single character. You could use `strlen()` to determine the length of the resulting string, but `snprintf()` already returns that, so it is more efficient to use that value:

```
    int len = snprintf( buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d\r", i ) ;
    write( STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, len ) ;
```

or

```
    write( STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, 
           snprintf( buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d\r", i ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 5):

`write(1,buffer,1);`

writes only one character to `stdout`.  The first digit in the string.

You want

`write(1,buffer,strlen(buffer));`

Comment: ... or use the `snprintf()` return value for the length.